# Is Pythagore's Theorem easy?

Tags: calculus

How to prove that 2 is the unique real solution of this equation : $ 3^x+4^x=5^x $

I try with $f(x)=3^x+4^x-5^x$ so $f'(x)=3^x\log(3)+4^x\log(4)-5^x\log(5)$

But I don't know how to do ...

Or it might be possible with algebra because $(e^{\lambda_1 x}, e^{\lambda_2 x}, e^{\lambda_3 x})$ is a linearly independent family (very easy to prove with the operator derivation "D" for the $C^\infty$ function because $D(e^{\lambda_i x})=\lambda_i e^{\lambda_i x}$ so ...)  but I don't know too.

Thank's for your help ! :)

Shadock

Comment: It isn't a special case of Fermat's last theorem -- $x \in \mathbb{R}$, not $x \in \mathbb{N}$. Split into cases for $x<2,x>2$ and show monotonicity.

Comment: Fermat's last theorem and 1 is not solution :D?

Comment: Yes, I'm just stupid !!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $0<a<1$, then the map $x\mapsto a^x$ is strictly decreasing for $x\ge 0$. Consequently there can be only one $x>0$ with $$\left(\frac35\right)^x+\left(\frac45\right)^x=1.$$

Comment: should work for all real $x.$ $$ \frac{d}{dx} a^x = a^x \log a  $$ and $a^x > 0$

Comment: Amazing but don't understand haha ^^

Comment: @Shadock, what is your background? Have you had calculus? Probably, you mention $C^\infty$ functions. My comment amounts to writing, for real number $a > 0, a \neq 1,$ $$ a^x = e^{x \; \log a} $$